# Open ID & Steam abort from load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having this issue since I put steam login to a website. Basicly, because the steam api sometimes takes about 40 seconds to load data, i made a javascript function on load to make the page load faster. This function loads after the page loaded so the steam api works at background. HOWEVER, while this function working [Code 1] if user leaves/refreshes page, the new page waits the previous loading function.

PS: All connections (database, steamapi..) are being made by connect.php that is bellow [Code 3]. This page is loading with 2 ways: With php include() function before page loads (With this way, I can include any required file such as database info, database connection) [Code 4]. And the second way is the javascript function bellow [Code 2].

PS 2: You can test it live on http://portal.sf-gaming.co.uk/portal/ by refreshing the page while the Loading… still appears next to copyright bar.

[Code 1 - The Steam Web API Script (userInfo.php)]

```
$api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Insert API Key here!

    $urla = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=" . $api_key; 
    $urlb = "&steamids=";
    $urlc = $urla . $urlb;
    $url = $urlc . $_SESSION['steamid'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $content = json_decode($content, true);

    $_SESSION['sp_steamid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];
    $_SESSION['sp_communityvisibilitystate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['communityvisibilitystate'];
    $_SESSION['sp_profilestate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['profilestate'];
    $_SESSION['sp_personaname'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
    $_SESSION['sp_lastlogoff'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['lastlogoff'];
    $_SESSION['sp_profileurl'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['profileurl'];
    $_SESSION['sp_avatar'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatar'];
    $_SESSION['sp_avatarmedium'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatarmedium'];
    $_SESSION['sp_avatarfull'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['avatarfull'];
    $_SESSION['sp_personastate'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['personastate'];
    $_SESSION['sp_realname'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['realname'];
    $_SESSION['sp_primaryclanid'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['primaryclanid'];
    $_SESSION['sp_timecreated'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['timecreated'];
    $_SESSION['sp_loccountry'] = $content['response']['players'][0]['loccountrycode'];

    $_SESSION['sp_steamid32'] = GetSteam32ID($_SESSION['steamid']);

    date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
    $_SESSION['sp_currenttime'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
    $_SESSION['sp_clientip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." | ".$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

[Code 2 - The Javascript Function]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loaddata()
{
    document.getElementById('page_loading').style.display = "block";
    $.post("<? echo $js_url."connect.php?refresh_steamdata=true&refresh_databasedata=true".$js_url_par; ?>",{
    },
    function(data)
    {
            document.getElementById('page_loading').style.display = "none";
            <? if($curpage == "My Account") { ?>
            document.getElementById("profileloadingBlanket").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("profileloadingDiv").style.display = "none";
            $("#profile_Area").load("account.php #profile_Area").fadeIn();
            <? } ?>
    });
}

loaddata();
</script>
```

[Code 3 - The connect.php being loaded by the function]

```
// Get Steam Data
if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']) and !isset($_SESSION['sp_steamid']) or $refreshall == true or $refresh_steamdata == true)
{
    include ("steamauth/userInfo.php");
    //echo "Executed userInfo.php and steamauth/userInfoWRITE.php \n";
}

// Get Database Data
if(!isset($_SESSION['mi_SteamID']) and isset($_SESSION['steamid']) or $refreshall == true or $refresh_databasedata == true)
{
    include("database_info.php");
    //echo "Executed database_info.php \n";
}
```

[Code 4 - include() function runs in every page like the javascript function.]

```
$refreshall= $_GET["refreshdata"];
include("../connections/connect.php");
```

[Edit 1]
I have some fixes in my mind:
1. Before unloading page, the javascript loading function can be aborted in some way.
2. Before unloading page, a php function can be ruined in a some way.  launching that code stops the json file (tools 40 seconds to load) from loading.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing it, but I'm not seeing a question. What if your question/problem?

Comment: I have some fixes in my mind: 1. Before unloading page, the javascript loading function can be aborted in some way. 2. Before unloading page, a php function can be ruined in a some way. launching that code stops the json file (tools 40 seconds to load) from loading.

Comment: You still haven't asked a question.